# How do I retrieved field value from other java class?

Tags: java, reflection, data-retrieval

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("other");
Field[] field = c.getDeclaredFields();
System.out.println("name of field: "+fieldA[0].getName());
```

I can retrieve field name from other `.java` file but not the value.

Example:

```
<other.java file>   public int namefield = 5;
```

from my `main.java` execute file

I would like to retrieved the field name and the value.

```
display: name of field: namefield  value: 5
```

Comment: Take a look at the `Field` documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html. It lists all kinds of `get()`, `getInt()`, etc. methods for retrieving the value. However, if the field you want is public, why not access it directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume your class, which you want to inspect is:

```
public class ClassA {
    private String someString = "foo";
    public String anotherString = "bar";
}
```

The call of `ClassA.class.getDeclaredFields()` will return an array with two elements, but as one of the fields is private it cannot be accessed directly. To be able to you have to make it accessible first:

```
ClassA objectOfTypeClassA = ...
for (Field f : objectOfTypeClassA.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
  f.setAccessible(true);
  System.out.println("Value of "+f.getName()+" in class "+ClassA.class.getName()+" is "+f.get(objectOfTypeClassA));
}
```

To retrieve the value of a non static field you need to pass along the object instance on which the field value is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getInt(java.lang.Object)) of `java.lang.reflect.Field`. There you can see the method `getInt()`

You have to call `field.getInt(object)` where object is an instance of the class `other`

Answer (score 0):

You can't retrieve the field value, because the (non-static) field's value is a property of an object, while you're only accessing it's class via reflection.

To get the value of the field, you'd first need an object `anObject` of class `other` and then you could call

```
field.getInt(anObject);
```

to get its nameField value.